# Multiple Virtual Host not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, drupal, joomla2.5

I have installed zend framework to my wamp but muiple vitual host not working in my wamp
    each time i opened for zend host my wamp home page get displayed

```
I have included the following code in httpd.conf file

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1 >

DocumentRoot "C:/zendy/public"
ServerName zendy

<Directory "C:/zendy/public">

AllowOverride Autconfig FileInfo Indexes Limited options

Order Deny,Allow

Allow from 127.0.0.1

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

I have also bind the address in my hosts file
    127.0.0.1 zendy
```

plz help...

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: Yes i restarted it now it's giving 403 forbidden error "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the port in the virtualhost settings and restart your webserver, then it should work.
Later edit: Windows has the other slash if I recall ...

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\zendy\public"
ServerName zendy
<Directory "C:\zendy\public">
AllowOverride Autconfig FileInfo Indexes Limited options
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks...it worked but now it is giving 403 forbidden error "You don't have permission to access / on this server".

Comment: Check the file permissions for your index.php file

Comment: By any chance is the public folder empty? If so, try adding an index.html file or enable Indexes ( you only it allowed to change from .htaccess, nothing else from vhost)